# Get Candle stick pattern at 2 min level when the RSI at 5 meets criteria

Tags: pine-script

my default time frame is 5 min
and my rsi setting is 4 bars

I would like to know the candlestick patterns at 2 min time frame only when the rsi level meets below criteria.
rsi above 85
rsi below 15
rsi between 40 to 60

i tried below code using google but it doesnt work lot of errors.

```
study(title = "Candles", overlay = true)

rsival = rsi(ccl,4)
cop = security(tickerid,"2",cop) 
ccl = security(tickerid,"2",ccl)
ch = security(tickerid,"2",ch)
cl = security(tickerid,"2",cl)

cop1 = security(tickerid,"2",open[1]) 
ccl1 = security(tickerid,"2",close[1])
ch1 = security(tickerid,"2",high[1])
cl1 = security(tickerid,"2",low[1])

cop2 = security(tickerid,"2",open[2]) 
ccl2 = security(tickerid,"2",close[2])
ch2 = security(tickerid,"2",high[2])
cl2 = security(tickerid,"2",low[2])
DojiSize = input(0.05, minval=0.01, title="Doji size")

a = if rsivalu > 90

data=(abs(cop - ccl) <= (ch - cl) * DojiSize)
plotchar(data, title="D", text='D', color=color.black)

data2=(ccl2 > cop2 and min(cop1, ccl1) > ccl2 and cop < min(cop1, ccl1) and ccl < cop )
plotchar(data2, title="ES", text='ES', color=color.red, location=location.abovebar)

data3=(ccl2 < cop2 and max(cop1, ccl1) < ccl2 and cop > max(cop1, ccl1) and ccl > cop )
plotchar(data3, title="MS", text='MS', color=color.lime, location=location.beclbar)

data4=(cop1 < ccl1 and cop > ccl1 and ch - max(cop, ccl) >= abs(cop - ccl) * 3 and min(ccl, cop) - cl <= abs(cop - ccl))
plotchar(data4, title="SS", text='SS', location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)

data5=(((ch - cl)>3*(cop -ccl)) and  ((ccl - cl)/(.001 + ch - cl) > 0.6) and ((cop - cl)/(.001 + ch - cl) > 0.6))
plotchar(data5, title="H", text='H', location=location.beclbar, color=color.black)

data5b=(((ch - cl)>3*(cop -ccl)) and  ((ch - ccl)/(.001 + ch - cl) > 0.6) and ((ch - cop)/(.001 + ch - cl) > 0.6))
plotshape(data5b, title= "IH", location=location.beclbar, color=color.black, style=shape.diamond, text="IH")

data6=(ccl1 > cop1 and cop > ccl and cop <= ccl1 and cop1 <= ccl and cop - ccl < ccl1 - cop1 )
plotshape(data6, title= "BRHI",  color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="BRHI")

data7=(cop1 > ccl1 and ccl > cop and ccl <= cop1 and ccl1 <= cop and ccl - cop < cop1 - ccl1 )
plotshape(data7,  title= "BUHI", location=location.beclbar, color=color.lime, style=shape.arrowup, text="BUHI")

data8=(ccl1 > cop1 and cop > ccl and cop >= ccl1 and cop1 >= ccl and cop - ccl > ccl1 - cop1 )
plotshape(data8,  title= "BRE", color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="BRE")

data9=(cop1 > ccl1 and ccl > cop and ccl >= cop1 and ccl1 >= cop and ccl - cop > cop1 - ccl1 )
plotshape(data9, title= "BUE", location=location.beclbar, color=color.lime, style=shape.arrowup, text="BUE")

data12=(cop1>ccl1 and cop>=cop1 and ccl>cop)
plotshape(data12, title= "BUK", location=location.beclbar, color=color.lime, style=shape.arrowup, text="BUK")

data13=(cop1<ccl1 and cop<=cop1 and ccl<=cop)
plotshape(data13, title= "BRK", color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="BRK")

data15=((ccl1>cop1)and(((ccl1+cop1)/2)>ccl)and(cop>ccl)and(cop>ccl1)and(ccl>cop1)and((cop-ccl)/(.001+(ch-cl))>0.6))
plotshape(data15, title= "DCC", color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="DCC")

else
    na
```

Comment: Sorry, but no one here will write the code for you. I recommend you [this](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/) and [this](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Pine_Script_Tutorial) tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the links